# Transforming UISearchbar

Tags: ios, animation, transform, uisearchbar

I have a search-bar with tableView below that search bar. I want to go full screen when the user tap search-bar for searching. But i am unable to set the frame to the origin of the UISearchBar.
 i doing it in this way.

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    [ [UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];

    [self.topBarView setHidden:YES];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:0
                     animations:^{
                         [self.searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, self.searchBar.frame.size.width,
                                                             self.searchBar.frame.size.height )];

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL completion){
                     }];
    [self.searchBar setNeedsDisplay];




}
```

}

[image]

[image]
I am hiding all the views above the search-bar and i am setting the origin to `0,0`
In the second image the top bar disappears but search-bar stays on its place. It should go at the top.
If somebody can identify the problem it will be great.
**I am also using auto-layout does this make cause any problem?**

Comment: use searchbar displaycontroller

Answer (score 0):

use searchbar display controller.it will achieve that

[image]

Comment: I am using it but i don't need the navigation controller and also need some customization. Thats why i am adding a view on top of search-bar that will act as a navigation controller

Comment: post your screen shot

Comment: Added screenshot. This top bar is a uiview which will go away and search-bar and tableview should should become full screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Add a search Bar & searchDisplay Controller to your controller.

UISearchBar *searchBar;
UITableView *tableView;
UISearchDisplayController *searchController;

```
 // Create table view
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_tableView.delegate         = self;
_tableView.dataSource       = self;
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];

// Create search bar
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0f)];
_searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
_searchBar.delegate         = self;
[self.view addSubview:_searchBar];
[_searchBar sizeToFit];

// Create search controller
_searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
_searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
_searchController.searchResultsDelegate   = self;
_searchController.delegate                = self;
```

Then you can perform this operation so that searchBar becomes responder & shows Keyboard.

```
[_searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

Hope that helps.